# Facebook always butchering my image on timeline

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, screenshot, facebook-opengraph

I've been working on an Android game, and I wanted to setup a webpage to redirect to the download page. This part was easy.

So I share it on my facebook timeline. Ok, my screenshot gets cropped horribly. Spend 30 minutes reading all sorts of guides on how to point facebook to the proper image for a thumbnail ...

No matter what I do, facebook always, always, always shows a horribly cropped image. I would like to simply specify the correct image to facebook using og:image but it seems to always ignore this. I've tried many different combinations of properties and it's always wrong. I've tried making the og:image square, doesn't matter. I've tried making it smaller, doesn't matter.

It's also hard to figure out if facebook is caching an old image or not, no matter how many times I go on the debug link and tell it to scrape things again.

Can anyone tell me any change I can make to show the entire image instead of the horrible cropped version?

I went to [http://validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) and made sure the page didn't have errors beyond the og ones you apparently can't avoid.

The page is: [www.playlunapuma.com](http://www.playlunapuma.com)

There must be a way to convince facebook to show a different image that looks good.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that finally worked was resizing the og:image to 600x315 exactly.